# Filling a logical field on whether a record exists Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Right now I have:

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET logical_field = 0 
 WHERE logical_field != 0
;

UPDATE table_name t 
   SET t.logical_field = 1 
 WHERE EXISTS 
   (SELECT 1
      FROM other_table s 
     WHERE s.key_field = t.key_field)
   AND t.logical_field != 1
;
```

This is a simplified version of my code. I want one statement that will set the logical based on the existence of another record and doesn't update it if it doesn't need to.

I've looked into 'decode' statements and I think that could work. Is decode the best for this or is there an easier way.

Using: Oracle 11g

Comment: Just for my sanity: you want to be able to do the 2 steps above (which result in the desired results) in 1 step.  Is my understanding of the problem correct?

Comment: the number of steps doesn't really matter to me. I want to limit my writes. the first statement is making changes and the second is coming along and changing some of them right back.

Comment: It is possible to write only one statement, but the trick here is to garantee the first update is done before the 2nd...

Comment: I feel like the first statement isn't necessary. all it's doing is wiping the field clean so the second statement can fill the true ones. I think using a decode statement one could decide the logical based on the existence of the record but I'm not very good with 'decode'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have the decode working. Let me know what you think and/or if there is a better way I'd like to learn it.

```
UPDATE table_name t 
   SET t.logical_field =
         decode((SELECT distinct s.key_field
                   FROM other_table s 
                  WHERE s.key_field = t.key_field), t.key_field, 1, 0)
 WHERE t.logical_field != 
         decode((SELECT distinct s.key_field
                   FROM other_table s 
                  WHERE s.key_field = t.key_field), t.key_field, 1, 0)
;
```